# _lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object

Tags: angular5, webpack-4, angular-aot, angular-compiler

I'm using angular compiler:
`const  AngularCompilerPlugin = require('@ngtools/webpack').AngularCompilerPlugin;`

With these compiler options:

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
"genDir": "./build/compiled",
"outDir": "./build/compiled",
"skipMetadataEmit": true,
"debug": true},
```

Relevant part of my package.json is:

```
"@ngtools/webpack": "^6.0.0",
"@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
"webpack": "4.8.3",
"webpack-cli": "2.1.4",
```

And my angularCompilerPlugin config is:

```
new AngularCompilerPlugin({
  tsConfigPath: 'path-to-tsconfig.webpack.json',
  entryModule: 'path-to-app.module#AppModule',
  sourceMap: true
}),
```

With these configurations, I'm getting:

```
ERROR in ./$$_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path-/alerts/module.ngfactory.js' in 'path-to-app-folder/$$_lazy_route_resource'
 @ ./$$_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object
 @ ./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js
 @ multi core-js/shim classlist.js reflect-metadata zone.js/dist/zone jquery/dist/jquery rxjs/Rx lodash jquery.panzoom moment moment-timezone @angular/common @angular/core @angular/http @angular/router @angular/forms semantic
```

Please any direction or help.

Comment: please add your tsconifg.json file to your question

Answer (score 7):

I was able to resolve this error by adding the Lazy Module `.ts` paths to my `ts.config-aot.json`  in the `files` section:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5", //most browsers currently understand this version of Javascript
        "experimentalDecorators": true, //Angular2 uses Component,Injectable etc
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true, //Required for Angular2 to use the metadata in our components
        "types": [
            "node",
            "jasmine"
        ],
        "lib": [
            "es2015",
            "es2015.iterable",
            "dom"
        ]
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ],
    "files": [
        "src/app/app.module.ts",
        "src/main.ts",
        "src/app.d.ts",
        "src/app/sandbox/sandbox.module.ts",
        "src/app/supplier-xchange/supplier-xchange.module.ts",
        "src/app/company-profile/company-profile.module.ts",
        "src/app/bom/bom.module.ts",
        "src/app/custom-price-column/custom-price-column.module.ts",
        "src/app/neca/neca.module.ts"
    ]
}
```

Comment: I am getting the same error, adding the modules in files helped me in resolving this issue.   Just wanted to understand, how to get rid of this manual configuration? Recently I've switched to another project where I've do such thing for all other project angular-cli pick this automatically from route-configuration