# Lazy Loaded Modules with AOT - TypeError: '' is not a function when served from NGINX

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, aot

Here are my dist files to reproduce yourself:

- [dist with Lazy Modules, AOT](https://www.dropbox.com/s/crlqwkci8v15zz6/dist-aot-uglify.zip?dl=0)
- [dist with Lazy Modules, no AOT](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qcb19eorjg7o41x/dist-no-aot.zip?dl=0)
- [dist with AOT, no Lazy Modules](https://www.dropbox.com/s/84z1athp6z08ffq/dist-aot-no-lazy.zip?dl=0)

The breakdown:

- My dist build, with AOT and Lazy Loaded modules works fine when served with npm packages webpack-dev-server or live-server
- It is only when I copy dist to NGINX html directory and NGINX serves the files that I see Javascript errors in Firefox and Chrome
- I have tried many different webpack configurations.
- I am not importing my Lazy Loaded modules in any Typescript file
- With AOT compilation OFF my app and Lazy Modules serve fine from NGINX
- **The TypeError: '' is not a function error is coming from Lazy Loaded Modules being served with NGINX**

I am using the official Angular package `@ngtools/webpack` to add AOT compilation to my Angular 5 app. [This article](https://blog.craftlab.hu/multiple-solutions-for-angular-ahead-of-time-aot-compilation-c474d9a0d508) explains how to use `@ngtools/webpack` to add AOT to a Webpack build project. Very simple, though the article does not mention the needed step to [add the Lazy Load module file paths](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51485469/1258525) to `tsconfig-aot.json`. AOT fails with out that step.

All works great localhost with:

```
npm run serve
```

My `npm run serve` command is an in memory compilation and the resources are served localhost from memory using the npm package `webpack-dev-server`.

When I deploy to my development server, the compilation files are stored on disk and my dev server serves the resources with `NGINX`.

I have lazy loaded modules that, when loaded are throwing strange errors like this in Firefox:

```
TypeError: i0.\u0275crt is not a function
```

[image]

And this in Chrome:

```
ERROR TypeError: i0.ɵcrt is not a function
```

[image]

Going to more detail with the error in Chrome, here is the source maps line of code throwing the error:
[image]

I see that the creation of var `i0` is this line:

```
var i0 = __webpack_require__(/*! @angular/core */ "./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js");
```

On my dev server, node_modules as at the parent level with my dist folder:
[image]

My files on my dev server:

[image]

Here is a comparison of the resource files served up from localhost:

[image]

And here is the resource files served up from the development server:
[image]

OK so here comes my configuration and npm package versions:

**webpack.config**

```
 var merge = require('webpack-merge'),
    htmlPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin'),
    revPlugin = require('webpack-rev-replace-plugin'),
    config = require('./build.config.json'),
    path = require('path'),
    extendedDefinePlugin = require('extended-define-webpack-plugin'),
    webpackDelPlugin = require('webpack-del-plugin'),
    openBrowserPlugin = require('open-browser-webpack-plugin'),
    uglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const AotPlugin = require('@ngtools/webpack').AngularCompilerPlugin;
//import {AngularCompilerPlugin} from '@ngtools/webpack';

//Note : in package.json the last variable (dev) is the param delivered to this function { env: 'dev' }. 
module.exports = function (env) {
    console.log('env configuration', env.env);
    /**
     * configPerTarget is merged with build.config.json based on the env passed
     * currently no configuration properties, this configPerTarget not in use per se, keeping just in case - Ogden 4-12-2018
     */
    var configPerTarget = {
        localhost: {
        },
        development: {
        },
        test: {
        },
        staging: {
        },
        production: {
        },
        maintenance: {
        }
    };

    // Note : '__dirname' is the root file path.
    const ROOT_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname);
    const DIST_DIR = path.join(ROOT_DIR, config.dist);

    // If no env make it dev
    if (!env) {
        env = {};
        env.env = config.envDevelopment;
    }

    //merge config with env specific configPerTarget
    config = merge(config, configPerTarget[env.env]);

    // this takes path variables from build.config.json and builds it with given env
    var appConfigPath = config.envs + config.appConfig.replace('{env}', env.env);


    var webPackConfig = {
        entry: ['babel-polyfill', config.src + config.entry],//main.ts
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, config.dist),
            filename: config.buildjs,
            sourceMapFilename: config.buildjsmap,
            chunkFilename: '[id].[hash:6].chunk.js'
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.html$/, use: 'raw-loader' },
                { test: /\.css$/, use: 'raw-loader' },
                {
                    test: /\.ts$/,
                    loaders: [
                        'ts-loader',
                        'angular2-template-loader',
                        'angular-router-loader']
                },
                {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
                },
                //For images. 
                { test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i, loader: 'file-loader?name=app/assets/images/[name].[ext]' },
                {
                    test: /\.(ttf|eot|woff|woff2)$/,
                    loader: 'file-loader'
                },
            ]
        },
        //https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/
        //Webpack 4.4 has its own mode development and production, which are environment modes
        //do Webpack 4.4 is handling the devtool sourcemap config where in the past it was not
        //looks like we no longer have to worry about setting devtool
        //https://github.com/damianobarbati/yarsk/blob/50b6f352a13ec2e778fa8b252f915550b6132964/config/webpack.config.js#L110
        //devtool: config.devtool,
        resolve: {
            modules: [__dirname + path.sep + 'src', __dirname, 'node_modules'],
            extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.scss', '.css']
        },
        plugins: [
            new htmlPlugin({
                template: config.src + config.index
            }),
            new revPlugin({
                cwd: config.src,
                files: '**/*.html',
                outputPageName: function (filename) {
                    return filename;
                },
                modifyReved: function (filename) {
                    return filename.replace(/(\/style\/|\/script\/)/, '')
                }
            }),
            //Makes AppConfig variable available in the application code. 
            new extendedDefinePlugin({
                AppConfig: require(appConfigPath)
            }),
            //Usefull if you need remove some files or folders before compilation processes. 
            //currently not used (no dist file).
            new webpackDelPlugin({ match: path.join(DIST_DIR, '*.*') }),
            //opens browser after compilation.
            new openBrowserPlugin({ url: 'http://localhost:8080' })
        ]
    }

    //********************************AOT Compilation*************************************** */
    //-- AOT Compilation from this point on, currently AOT runs in all environments
    //this seems helpful because you get to see AOT build errors before pushing to build server
    //the downside might be more mangled code and harder to debug source code...

    if (env.env === config.envLocalhost) return webPackConfig;

    webPackConfig.module.rules.push(
        { test: /\.ts$/, loaders: ['@ngtools/webpack'] }
    );

    webPackConfig.plugins.push(new AotPlugin({
        tsConfigPath: './tsconfig-aot.json',
        //mainPath: path.resolve('./src/main.ts'),
        entryModule: path.join(config.src, 'app/app.module#AppModule')
    }));

    webPackConfig.optimization = {
        minimizer: [
            new uglifyJSPlugin({
                uglifyOptions: {
                    output: {
                        comments: false,
                        ascii_only: true
                    }
                }
            })
        ]
    }

    return webPackConfig;
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "tsl-frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start",
    "build-localhost": "webpack --mode development --progress --colors --env.env localhost",
    "build-development": "webpack --mode development --progress --colors --env.env development",
    "build-staging": "webpack --mode production --progress --colors --env.env staging",
    "build-production": "webpack --mode production -p --progress --colors --env.env production",
    "build-maintenance": "webpack --mode production -p --progress --colors --env.env maintenance",
    "serve": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --inline --progress --colors --env.env development",
    "serve-production": "webpack-dev-server --mode production --inline --progress --colors --env.env development",
    "serve-localhost": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --inline --progress --colors --env.env localhost",
    "serve-host": "webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80 --disable-host-check --mode development --inline --progress --colors --env.env localhost",
    "serve-maintenance": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --inline --progress --colors --env.env maintenance"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.11",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.1.2",
    "@types/file-saver": "^1.3.0",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^8.0.5",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.2",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.8",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "moment": "2.18.1",
    "moment-timezone": "0.5.13",
    "ng2-bootstrap-modal": "1.0.1",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
    "ng2-drag-drop": "^2.9.2",
    "ng2-page-scroll": "^4.0.0-beta.12",
    "ng2-toastr": "^4.1.2",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.5.5",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "typescript": "^2.9.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.11.19",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^6.0.8",
    "@servicestack/client": "^1.0.14",
    "@types/file-saver": "^1.3.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.8",
    "@types/node": "7.0.7",
    "angular-router-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "angular2-router-loader": "^0.3.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "extended-define-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.8",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-alpha",
    "jasmine": "^2.99.0",
    "karma": "^1.7.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "^2.0.13",
    "ng-intercom": "^1.0.0-beta.5-2",
    "ng2-tree": "^2.0.0-rc.11",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.2",
    "open-browser-webpack-plugin": "0.0.5",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.7",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.2",
    "text-mask-addons": "^3.7.2",
    "toposort": "^1.0.7",
    "ts-loader": "^4.4.2",
    "webpack": "^4.16.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.1.5",
    "webpack-del-plugin": "0.0.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.3",
    "webpack-rev-replace-plugin": "^0.1.1"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig-aot.json (files array includes lazy loaded module paths)**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5", //most browsers currently understand this version of Javascript
        "experimentalDecorators": true, //Angular2 uses Component,Injectable etc
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true, //Required for Angular2 to use the metadata in our components
        //"sourceMap": true
        "types": [
            "node",
            "jasmine"
        ],
        // "typeRoots": [
        //     "node_modules/@types"
        // ],
        "lib": [
            "es2015",
            "es2015.iterable",
            "dom"
        ]
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ],
    "files": [
        "src/app/app.module.ts",
        "src/main.ts",
        "src/app.d.ts",
        "src/app/sandbox/sandbox.module.ts",
        "src/app/supplier-xchange/supplier-xchange.module.ts",
        "src/app/company-profile/company-profile.module.ts",
        "src/app/bom/bom.module.ts",
        "src/app/custom-price-column/custom-price-column.module.ts",
        "src/app/neca/neca.module.ts"
    ],
    "angularCompilerOptions": {
        "genDir": "aot", // Specify where Angular can create temporary AOT files
        "skipMetadataEmit": true // Don't generate not necessary metadata files. They are useful only if you're publishing an Angular UI library
    }
}
```

And here is my NGINX configuration:

```
daemon off;
user  nginx;
worker_processes  2;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
    use epoll;
    accept_mutex off;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    client_max_body_size 300m;
    client_body_buffer_size 300k;
    large_client_header_buffers 8 64k;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_http_version 1.0;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_min_length 0;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml text/javascript application/xml application/xml+rss application/javascript application/json;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";
    gzip_vary on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}


server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;

    # API Server
    # location /api/ {
    #     proxy_pass ${MY_API_URL}/;
    # }

    # Main
    location / {
        set $cors "true";
       if ($http_origin ~* (http:\/\/d\.mywebsite\.com\S*)$) {
            set $cors "true";
        }

        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            set $cors "${cors}options";
        }

        if ($request_method = 'GET') {
            set $cors "${cors}get";
        }
        if ($request_method = 'POST') {
            set $cors "${cors}post";
        }

        if ($cors = "trueget") {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        }

        if ($cors = "truepost") {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        }

        if ($cors = "trueoptions") {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Content-Type,Accept,Origin,User-Agent,DNT,Cache-Control,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
            return 204;
        }

        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /index.html;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Do think these files matter to this problem but just in case:

**main.ts**

```
//CSS STYLES
import './styles';
import 'reflect-metadata';
//Zone JS is required by Angular itself.
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';


//remaining in ProdMode even in dev because of  ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked errors
//http://www.allenhashkey.com/web-development/angular2/angular-2-expression-changed-after-it-has-been-checked-exception/
enableProdMode();
// if (!AppConfig.isDevelopment) {
//     enableProdMode();
// }


platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .then(success => console.log('Bootstrap success'))
    .catch(err => console.error("Bootstrap module failure: ", err));
```

**app.module.ts**

```
// Vendor
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { Ng2DragDropModule } from 'ng2-drag-drop';
import { ToastModule } from 'ng2-toastr/ng2-toastr';
import { Ng2PageScrollModule } from 'ng2-page-scroll';
// Routing
import { AppRoutingModule, routableComponents } from './app-routing.module';
//Components
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
//Shared Module
import { SharedModule } from './@shared/shared.module';
//Feature Modules
import { CoreModule } from './@core/core.module';
import { DashboardModule } from './dashboard/dashboard.module';
import { ProductModule } from './product/product.module';
import { SearchModule } from './search/search.module';
import { LoginModule } from './login/login.module';
import { ExampleModule } from './example/example.module';
import { ProfileModule } from './profile/profile.module';
import { ResetPasswordModule } from './reset-password/reset-password.module';
import { EdataFlexModule } from './e-data-flex/e-data-flex.module';
import { SubmittalManagerModule } from './submittal-manager/submittal-manager.module';
import { PimModule } from './pim/pim.module';
import { AnalyticsModule } from './analytics/analytics.module';
import { InviteUserModule } from './invite-user/invite-user.module';
import { DownloadsModule } from './downloads/downloads.module';
import { SettingsModule } from './settings/settings.module';
import { ChangeBulletinModule } from './change-bulletin/change-bulletin.module';
//Singletons - A Singleton Service shall only be kept in app.module.ts "providers" (array)
//and it shall not be placed in any other component or service provider (array).
import { TokenService } from './@core/auth/token.service';
// Intercom Module
import { IntercomModule } from 'ng-intercom';
import { BootstrapModalModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap-modal';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    BrowserModule,
    DashboardModule,
    ProductModule,
    SearchModule,
    ProfileModule,
    ExampleModule,
    LoginModule,
    CoreModule,
    ResetPasswordModule,
    EdataFlexModule,
    SubmittalManagerModule,
    PimModule,
    AnalyticsModule,
    InviteUserModule,
    DownloadsModule,
    SettingsModule,
    ChangeBulletinModule,
    //Do not import feature modules below "AppRoutingModule"
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BootstrapModalModule.forRoot({container:document.body}),
    Ng2PageScrollModule.forRoot(),
    Ng2DragDropModule.forRoot(),
    ToastModule.forRoot(),
    IntercomModule.forRoot({
      appId:AppConfig.intercom["appId"], // TSO App Id
      updateOnRouterChange : true // will automatically run 'update' on router event changes.
    })
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    routableComponents
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy },
    TokenService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]

})
export class AppModule {
  /**
     * Allows for retrieving singletons using `AppModule.injector.get(MyService)`
     * This is good to prevent injecting the service as constructor parameter.
     */
  static injector: Injector;
  constructor(injector: Injector) {
    AppModule.injector = injector;
  }
}
```

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but are you using one of the build-* scripts before copying your destination files to your server?

Comment: I am using the build-development script currently before copying the output from dist to my dev server

Comment: Maybe going to the network tab (debug window) on your browser with localhost first, then comparing with your server, may help you figure out if there is anything missing.

Comment: @closevoter Dear closevoter, as someone who has struggled a lot in the past with mysterious angular/webpack errors, this looks like a perfectly valid question to me...

Comment: That is a good suggest, thanks, trying it out

Comment: @yms I updated my question to include network resource screenshots of both localhost and dev server

Comment: try to run with `optimization:false and buildOptimizer:false` so that you can see error more clear.

Comment: @RaviSevta thanks, but I am not using @angular/cli, thus I am not using ng build

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because when you use AOT, the code is uglified with some funny UTF-8 symbols; `ɵ` in `i0.ɵcrt` in your case

You need to tell nginx to use UTF-8 charset

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
  server_name _;

  charset UTF-8; #<==== Add this
```

Comment: thank you so much, I spent a great deal of time trying to figure out what the issue was here

Comment: No worries. It was easy to reproduce when I downloaded you files :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace your current nginx.conf file in the /etc/nginx folder with the following,

```
#worker_processes 2;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
   sendfile on;

   gzip on;
   gzip_disable "msie6";

   gzip_vary on;
   gzip_proxied any;
   gzip_comp_level 6;
   gzip_buffers 16 8k;
   gzip_http_version 1.1;
   gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    log_format timed_combined '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
    '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
    '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" '
    '$request_time $upstream_response_time $pipe';

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log timed_combined;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name _;
        return 404;
    }

   server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.example.com;

        location / {
           root /home/pokusr/propok-frontend/dist;
           try_files $uri /index.html;
        }
        location ~* "^/[a-z0-9]{40}.(css|js)$" {
            root /home/usr/proj_path/dist/;
            access_log off;
            expires max;
        }
    }
}
```

Lazy loaded routes will have the hash values in it and `location ~* "^/[a-z0-9]{40}.(css|js)$" {` this will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 8 we need to change old way of lazy loading style to dynamic import and need to change module: 'esnext' and target: 'es2015' in tsconfig.json file.